# Batch Formatting Utility not recognizing chosen drive letter

Tags: batch-file, formatting, ntfs

I know this is probably something silly, and I'm not an expert batch programmer by any means, but I'm running into a little problem.

I stripped the back-up function out of my back-up script (which works wonderfully) and attempted to make it a formatting script. Code included:

```
@echo off
title CrucialBlue Simple Format Utility
echo Drives will be formatted, and all data will be lost! Please ensure the drive letter you chose is correct before continuing
echo Retrieving list of disk locations...
wmic logicaldisk get caption,volumename,providername
echo.
set /p drive=Enter only the drive letter of the drive you're attempting to format: 
set /p form=Enter a file system to use (NTFS/FAT/FAT32):
echo.

IF EXIST %drive% format %drive%: /q fs:%form%
IF NOT EXIST %drive% echo Your drive was not formated because the drive you entered does not exist.
echo.

echo Program completed. Press any key...
pause > nul
```

I think the issue lies in my IF EXIST statement, where the actual function calls to both of the variables... Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: if exist b:\ will not work when the disk is not formatted, which is curious for a formatting utility.  OTOH if the disk is always already formatted then you need to use `if exist %drive%:\ (format blah) else (echo go away or I shall taunt you a second time)` and note the backslash on the drive letter

Comment: did you test my code? I'm interested in ....

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
IF EXIST %drive% format %drive%: /q fs:%form%
```

to

```
IF EXIST %drive%: format %drive%: /q fs:%form%
```

(Note the added `:` after the first `%drive%`)

Comment: Still giving me an error. B is a partition I set up to test this with. It's 1000MB and currently formatted in FAT. (B was the first available drive letter in the list.)


Enter only the drive letter of the drive you're attempting to format: B
Enter a file system to use (NTFS/FAT/FAT32):ntfs

Invalid parameter - fs:ntfs
Your drive was not formated because the drive you entered does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it if you use the built-in associative arrays from batch:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
title CrucialBlue Simple Format Utility
echo Drives will be formatted, and all data will be lost! Please ensure the drive letter you chose is correct before continuing
echo Retrieving list of disk locations...
for /f %%a in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption') do set "$%%a=1"
wmic logicaldisk get caption,volumename,providername
echo.
set /p "drive=Enter only the drive letter of the drive you're attempting to format: "
set /p "form=Enter a file system to use (NTFS/FAT/FAT32): "
echo(
IF DEFINED $%drive%: (
    ECHO format %drive%: /q fs:%form%
) ELSE (
    echo Your drive was not formatted because the drive you entered does not exist.
)
echo(
```

Look at the output and remove `ECHO` if it looks good.